# Cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста, удалил, файл xml, захотел скомпилировать приложение и по всему пошла запись Cannot resolve symbol R, уже все перепробовал, и перезагружал, и Clean project, rebuild project, и чистил кэш всё ровно вот такая ерунда. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте удалить ваш импорт к файлу R. И заново импортировать его, возможно у вас указана не верный путь к R

Comment: Вопрос ещё как это сделать куда лезть?

Comment: в MainActivity у вас сразу. Перед классом, где import подключенных классов

Comment: там нету его вообще

Comment: тогда нажмите на R, и после ctrl+enter и импортируйте его

Comment: Там есть только создать и переименовать все...

Comment: А всё спасибо разобрался в xml была беда