# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbor 'R', что делать?

Tags: android-studio

Только начал изучить разработку на Android. По видео с ютуба установил Android Studio, создал первый проект с Empty Activity. Сразу же в ИДЭ вылезла подсказка красным: Cannot resolve symbor 'R'
в коде MainActivity.java:

```
package com.test.myfirstapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Пробовал Build - Clean Project, Rebuild Project, File - Invalidate Caches

Android SDK установлены 15, 17 и 27 версии.
В build.gradle прописано:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 15
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.myfirstapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0 rc2'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

(По курсу используется sdk 15 версии)
При попытке забилдить вылезает:

```
AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Самое главное, что я не понимаю, что вообще происходит и куда копать, т.к. только начал с этим всем разбираться.

Может кто подсказать?

Comment: Сталкивался с похожей проблемой, помогал Gradle sync или перезапуск студии. Можете почитать комменты здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663850/cannot-resolve-symbol-r?rq=1 , может поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка на ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736532/232034

> Суть ошибки AAPT2 в том что теперь Android Studio ищет ресурсы
>   ".gradle" в пути "С://User//пользователь//.gradle". И если у вас имя
>   пользователя прописано русским алфавитом - то каюк.:) это
>   текстирование изменения. (хотя до обновления это прокатывало))).
>
> Исправляется следующим образом в настройках: -> Settings -> Build,
>   Execution -> Gradle -> Изменить строчку "Service directory path" на
>   "C:/Users/Public/.gradle"
>
> После этого сделать ребилд проекта и - вуаля! все работает. И с новыми
>   проектами уже проблем не будет.